# What coffeescript generates this js?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've been racking my brain (and google) over this and can't seem to find the answer.

**What coffeescript code would generate the following javascript?**

```
var Helper = {
  expandTextarea: function() {
    alert("BOOM AGAIN!");
  }
};
```

Comment: http://js2coffee.org/ usually does a good job, particularly with small snippets like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Helper = expandTextarea: ->
  alert "BOOM AGAIN!"
```

Comment: Example here: http://coffeescript.org/#try:Helper%20%3D%20expandTextarea%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20alert%20%22BOOM%20AGAIN!%22

Comment: Thanks. The thing that confused me though is that cs will wrap everything in an anonomous function, preventing me from calling `Helper.expandTextarea` initially. Big gotcha for me.

Comment: @ErwinM If you need to make `Helper` globals, use `window.Helper = ...`